# Provide semantic grammar to OK Glass menu

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

When registering a menu item for the "OK Glass..." I'd like to some how provide a different semantic value to what is actually displayed. The example I have is "OK glass, find an ATM" is difficult for Glass to recognise and I'm thinking this is because it is expecting the word "ATM" instead of "A-T-M". If possible can I somehow provide these semantics into the menu whilst displaying an alternate message?

Comment: I've been searching for the same thing. I think a feature request.

Comment: would phonetically spelling out the voice trigger in voice_trigger_scan.xml but changing the displayed text help your case?

Answer (score 0):

The Glass Developers [Voice Command Checklist](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-checklist) and [Voice Input](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice) pages both recommend using a generic trigger under the "ok glass" menu, immediately followed by speech recognition to determine specific/unique parts of the request.

Could you use something like: "ok glass, **find the nearest location for**..."

... and then recognize the speech for "...**A-T-M**".

Here is the example used on the Voice Command Checklist:

> "ok glass, find a recipe for..." (this allows users to speak "chicken kiev" and immediately see the recipe)

This approach also has the benefit of being generic enough to have your Glassware locate a number of places, not just an ATM.